# String em php é uma classe?

Tags: php

String em java é uma classe especial, onde vc pode instanciar o objeto apenas atribuindo um valor sem usar a palavra reservada `new`. Mas em php quando inicializamos uma variavel com um texto, podemos dizer que estamos instanciando um objeto da classe String?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Não.** No PHP, [`string`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) é um dos [oito tipos primitivos](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php) disponíveis. Quando você atribui uma string a uma variável, não é possível invocar métodos nela. Não ocorre [*autoboxing*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) em um tipo de objeto correspondente.